# How to replace an ID foreign key with name field of the Primary key in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Question 1: I am working on a leave portal with Laravel, and each staff going on leave is expected to select a relief staff. So in my database, I have a Staff Table, and Leave Table. The leave Table has id, staff_id, and relief_staff_id

Now i want to return a table in the view showing all leave requests in a tabular format with "Staff Name, Relief Staff name etc.

Have setup my model and its relationship.
In my LeavesController, I have done a query to join my leave and staff table, but since this query will only return all leave records matching staff records, but not replace 'relief_staff_id' with 'name', I need to do another query while looping through data gotten from the previous query, to **select staff_name from Staff table where id = relief_staff_id.**

But, each time I do a foreach loop on the result of previous query, it only returns 1 line of data to the view.

I tried assigning each value including the newly introduced 'relief_staff_name' into an associative array, yet when i return the array, it will have just 1 record..

Even tried doing an array_push, yet i cant work with the data in the view.
How can I solve this please?

How can I use foreach loop on array data in my controller, assign extra values to each data, and also return all the data in the array to be passed to my view?

Now am tempted to run queries in my view.

See code

```
public function history()
    {
        $application_history = 'yes';
        $loggedStaffId = Auth::user()->id;        
        $refinedData = array();

        //** Internal Function for decoding the relief staff name using the returned ID */
        function show_relief_staff($relief_staff_id)
        {
            $data = staff::find($relief_staff_id);
            return $data->name;
        }

        //** Joing Leave and Staff Tables */
        $rawData = \DB::table('staffs')
                        ->join('leaves', 'staffs.id', '=', 'leaves.staff_id')
                        ->select('leaves.*', 'staffs.name','staffs.email')
                        ->where('leaves.staff_id', '=', 1)
                        ->get();      
        //return $rawData;
        //** Lopping to replace relief staff Id with his name */
        foreach($rawData as $x)
        {
            $refinedData[]=$x;
            //$refinedData['relief_staff_name'] = show_relief_staff($x->relief_staff);
            $push = show_relief_staff($x->relief_staff);
            array_push($refinedData, $push);
            // $refinedData['staff_name'] = $x->name;
            // $refinedData['leave_type'] = $x->leave_type;
            // $refinedData['days_requested'] = $x->days_requested;
            // $refinedData['days_approved'] = $x->days_approved;
            // $refinedData['start_date'] = $x->start_date;
            // $refinedData['end_date'] = $x->end_date;
            // $refinedData['staff_comment'] = $x->staff_comment;
            // $refinedData['status'] = $x->status;
            // $refinedData['created_at'] = $x->created_at;
            // $refinedData['updated_at'] = $x->updated_at;
            // $refinedData['relief_staff'] = show_relief_staff($x->relief_staff);
        }


        return view('leave.history',compact('rawData', 'refinedData', 'application_history'));
    }
```

Comment: why you can't use $refinedData['staff_name'] = $x->name; code?